# Apache Spark: issue with Scala example

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, apache-spark

I'm trying to learn to use Apache Spark and I have a problem with a simple example but I can not find a solution. I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04 with Java-7-Oracle and scala 2.9.3.
When I try to run SparkPi examples I get this output:

```
filippo@filippo-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

This is the example show in Spark documentation but I don't understand what is the problem :(

Comment: Can you write your spark version and the documentation you tried to follow?

Comment: Spark version 1.1.1 and this is the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have downloaded a source release rather than a pre-built?

To build and assemble with sbt, you can run `sbt assembly` in the spark root directory.

Comment: I downloaded a pre-built release :)

Comment: The solution was the command `sbt/sbt clean assembly`! With this the example run correctly! :)

Comment: Strange. If you downloaded pre-built release, you don't need to build it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation directory is /usr/local/spark, which doesn't contain the required class.

Try just extract the downloaded tgz file from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. Cd to the directory and run the example command.

Make sure that you have lib/spark-examples-XXX-YYY.jar when you run bin/run-example